# Unable to get selected value from ion-select in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to get the selected option Value from ion-select 
but when I select any value from ion-select I am getting **Undefined** value since I am new to ionic 
I was unable to sort it on my own.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
   <ion-select [(ngModel)]="number"  
     (ionChange)="onChange(carbrand)" >
      <ion-option *ngFor="let count of quantity" 
       [value]="count" >{{count}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
   <!-- <ion-select [(ngModel)]="number">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let count of quantity" 
      value="count"></ion-option>
   </ion-select> -->
</ion-item>
```

**Home.ts :**

```
onChange(SelectedValue){ 
  console.log("Selected Quantity", SelectedValue); 
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use two other approaches.

1 - Pass $event to your function:

Html:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="number" (ionChange)="onChange($event)" >
      <ion-option *ngFor="let count of quantity" value="count"></ion-option>
    </ion-select>
    <!-- <ion-select [(ngModel)]="number">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let count of quantity" value="count"></ion-option>
    </ion-select> -->
</ion-item>
```

Ts:

```
onChange(value){
  console.log(value);
}
```

2 - Use an Id in your select element:

Html:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
    <ion-select #S [(ngModel)]="number" (ionChange)="onChange(S.value)" >
      <ion-option *ngFor="let count of quantity" value="count"></ion-option>
    </ion-select>
    <!-- <ion-select [(ngModel)]="number">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let count of quantity" value="count"></ion-option>
    </ion-select> -->
</ion-item>
```

Ts:

```
onChange(value){
  console.log(value);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: In your first approach, [value]="count" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

that's because onChange is sending your **carbrand** which is probably undefined. 
What you need to do is use the class property number that you must have declared as follow :

```
onChange(){
    console.log("Selected Quantity", this.number); 
}
```

And remove the **carbrand** unless it has a value in the template or as class property